# High voltage input window comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, high-voltage, comparator

I'm trying to find pieces (comparators or op amp) to make a window voltage comparator. My window range is 180VDC to 230VDC. Did you ever heard of high voltage input comparators? I don't need a high voltage supply, all I want to do with my window is to drive a LED to know if the voltage is in the window of not.

Thanks a lot

Boris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just divide the voltages down to something reasonable. If you use a CMOS-input comparator, or op-amps as a comparator, you can use very high value resistors without significant loss of accuracy.

BTW, I presume you are talking about **DC** here, otherwise the problem is a bit different.

If you used a 10M + 101K resistors you would have a 1.8V to 2.3VDC output and you could use a 5V supply for the circuit.

Comment: The only argument *against* this is if the DC voltage is extremely low power, in which case you can't afford to waste 20 microamps. But that's probably not the case here...

Comment: It works perfectly. But what about a Zener diode? Is it possible to achieve the same thing using the zener voltage?

Comment: It is possible, but I don't think it would lend any advantages.

Comment: I don't think that's low power, that sounds like a traction battery monitoring circuit to me.

Answer (score 2):

I simulated this using LT1017's, but any comparator(s) capable of sinking >=20 mA or so should work.

[image]